# Does the WiFi alliance protect the protocol documentation?

Tags: design, wifi

I was recently studying the IEEE 802.11 standards for WiFi (pretty dry stuff, huh?) and I was wondering this:

**Would it be theoretically possible for someone not in the WiFi alliance to develop a chip without a whole lot of reverse engineering? How hard would it be for an individual to develop this without wasting his/her whole life's savings and 10 years of their life?** I am a person who likes to innovate, and I would think that it would be cool to figure out how to create a cheap Arduino compatible device for WiFi.

### NOW HOLD ON:

I know what you're thinking: "*IT CAN'T BE DONE!*" I was more looking at about how tied down the information about the devices are. I would never dream of trying to mess around with HDMI and all the patents and such, but I was wondering since WiFi was anything from the first few generations of WiFi left that could be used? Since it is an older technology, I would imagine that information was more freely avaliable back then, and was wondering if it **theoretically possible** without loosing that persons sanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wi-Fi Alliance is a trademark management corporation. None certified products are produced all the time. The only thing the Wi-Fi Alliance does is license the name "Wi-Fi" and certifies for inter-optibility with the official 802.11 specs.

802.11b/g/n is fairly open, and the specs are managed by the IEEE, not the Wi-Fi Alliance. None certified, none patent paying wi-fi compatible products are produced all the time.

But you would pretty much need decades of experience and a ton of free time or money to produce a consumer capable wifi chip, from scratch, as a single engineer.

Comment: For a commercial product, you'd also need to be very careful not to infringe existing patents. Patent terms are 20 years from filing.